# JpaRepository.findOne(long id) is not working of Spring data jpa

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two services in Spring boot.  From the main service i am calling another service which insert a row in the DB as following:

```
repo.saveAndFlush(payment);
```

As soon as the child service finishes its work in the main service i didn't get the updated response using following query:

```
repo.findOne(id);
```

Its all happening synchronously. I want to get all the rows using findOne() method including newly inserted row.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually JpaRepository save methods return the newly saved data. So you can simply get the newly inserted row by doing something like this -

`payment = repo.saveAndFlush(payment`);